# Which URL's are used by Xcode to communicate with Apple's servers

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I am looking to block the developer's machines to communicate with Apple servers.

Some places we need to communicate:

1. Adding an account
2. Validating certificate and auto signing
3. Validating Profiles
4. Uploading an `.ipa` to AppStore Connect
5. Anything else(legacy services?)...

Can anyone list the url's for the above services?

Answer (score 1):

I used Charles to check the urls, this is what I found:

- https://devimages-cdn.apple.com
- http://ocsp.apple.com
- https://developerservices2.apple.com
- https://contentdelivery.itunes.apple.com
- http://ocsp.digicert.com
- https://gs-loc.apple.com